# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure <procedure_name>, Line 40 Incorrect syntax near '('

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
select * from dbo.split(RTRIM(@importRow), '¬')
```

gives error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure proc_name, Line 40
>   Incorrect syntax near '('.

What is the correct syntax for this line? It's been a while since I have done SQL properly and can't for the life of me get this part of the script to execute!

Using SQL Server 2005

I apologise for the Title. Not quite sure what to put other than that or "Syntax error"!

Edit: The code for the SPLIT:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
        @String VARCHAR(4000),
        @Delimiter VARCHAR(5)
)
RETURNS @SplittedValues TABLE
(
  OccurenceId SMALLINT IDENTITY(1,1),
  SplitValue VARCHAR(4000)
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SplitLength INT

WHILE LEN(@String) > 0
BEGIN
        SELECT @SplitLength = (CASE CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) WHEN 0 THEN
LEN(@String) ELSE CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) -1  END)

        INSERT INTO @SplittedValues
        SELECT SUBSTRING(@String,1,@SplitLength)

        SELECT @String = (CASE (LEN(@String) - @SplitLength) WHEN 0 THEN ''
ELSE RIGHT(@String, LEN(@String) - @SplitLength - 1) END)
END
RETURN
END
GO
```

And the code for starting the procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.[procedure] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@RETURN_VALUE int,
@importRow VarChar(8000)
......
```

Comment: If you comment this line out? Line numbers do not always match the actual line..

Comment: Are you trying to do ``select dbo.split(RTRIM(@importRow), '¬')``?

Comment: @gbn :Funny to mention that, this is the line it get to when I double click on the error. Which is line 52(ish) The actual line is a blank line

Comment: @ChristianWattengård a split function will usually be a table valuied function to split a delimited text string and return rows to get around the fact that you can't do WHERE IN (@CsvString)

Comment: @ChristianWattengård . This came close, but then came up with an error along the lines of "INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list"

Comment: Try running that line by itself it is probably fine, the error is likely somewhere before it and that is the first piece of valid SQL it recognises.

Comment: `dbo.split` is an UDF function or stored procedure? (scalar-valued UDF / table-value ???)

Comment: @BenRobinson : Same error when ran by itself

Comment: **Show us** the definition of `dbo.split` ! Otherwise, we can only guess....

Comment: @RawryLions If you get that error when you run it by itself then the error is in the split function, please post the code for that.

Comment: @BenRobinson Code for the split added

Comment: Show please declarartion of the `@importRow`

Comment: @sll :added the start of the procedure where its created. It doesnt have a `DECLARE @importRow varchar(8000)` anywhere though?

Comment: Try without the RTRIM please (but should't make a difference

Comment: Is it not in the part `INSERT INTO @SplittedValues SELECT SUBSTRING(@String,1,@SplitLength)` ? `@SplittedValues` has two columns and you are inserting just one string... Maybe `INSERT INTO @SplittedValues(SplitValue) SELECT SUBSTRING(@String,1,@SplitLength)` would do the job.

Comment: @gbn : This seems to have worked for the query. I assume this shouldn't alter how this works. I will go and do some testing first before I mark this as answered.

Comment: I just tested your code in sql 2008 (all i have installed) and it works fine, I suspect the issue here may not be with this particular line but one of the lines before it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the RTRIM into the UDF itself (based on comments)

This is good practice anyway so each use of the `split` UDF doeen't need RTRIM